# How do I rearrange columns in a text file?

Tags: text-processing, awk

```
Month   Name  Marks  
2016-10 Sam   58  
2016-09 Sam   77  
2016-10 John  64  
2016-09 John  47  
2016-10 Mark  71  
2016-09 Mark  38  
2016-10 Steve 83  
2016-09 Steve 39
```

I fetch this data from my DB having month in 1st column and marks in 3rd column for each student in 2nd column. Now i want to edit in such way that it contains the name in 1st column, marks for 2016-10 in 2nd column and then marks for 2016-09 in third column.

Comment: I edited your title but I see that it's still not clear; what you really want is to create something like a "pivot table", right?

Comment: I'm beginning to love [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/manual/datamash.html) for tasks like this: `datamash -WH groupby "Name" collapse "Marks" < data` OTOH if the input is coming from a database, it's hard to imagine that it couldn't be better done with a native `select` ... `group by` query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your input data is in a file called `grades, try:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"} NR==1{next} {m[$1]; n[$2]; g[$2,$1]=$3} END{for (name in n) {printf "%s",name; for (month in m) printf " %s",g[name,month]; print""}}' grades | column -t
Steve  83  39
Sam    58  77
Mark   71  38
John   64  47
```

The output has one row per student with the grades presented in descending order of month.

For those who prefer their code spread out over multiple lines:

```
gawk '
    BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"}
    NR==1{
        next
    }

    {
        m[$1]
        n[$2]
        g[$2,$1]=$3
    }

    END{
        for (name in n) {
            printf "%s",name
            for (month in m)
                printf " %s", g[name,month]
                print""
        }
    }

    ' grades | column -t
```

#### How it works

- `BEGIN{ PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_desc"}`

  This tells awk that we want arrays sorted in indices.  This is a GNU feature.
- `NR==1{next}`

  This tells awk to skip over the first line.  If you want to add a header for the output file, we could do it here.
- `m[$1]`

  This tells awk to add an entry for the current month in associative array `m`.  We don't need to assign a value because we will simply use this to track which months are present in the input.
- `n[$2]`

  This tells awk to add an entry for the student name in associative array `n`.  We don't need to assign a value because we will simply use this to track which months are present in the input.
- `g[$2,$1]=$3`

  This assigns the grade as a the value under the key of student name, month in associative array `g`.
- `END{for (name in n) {printf "%s",name; for (month in m) printf " %s",g[name,month]; print""}}`

  After we have reached the end of the file, we print out all the names and grades for each student.
- `column -t`

  This optional step makes the output pretty.

Answer (score 0):

If you need double month

```
sed '
    2~2{                                               #for even lines
        N                                              #attach next line
        s/\(\S\+ \)\(\S\+ \)[0-9]*\n\(\S\+\).*/\2\1\3/ #rearrange two line
    }
    1c\Name Month1 Month2                              #output new header
    ' file.data
```

Or double marks

```
sed '
    1!N             #from second line attach next line 
    s/\S\+ //       #remove first field (2016-10)
    s/\n.* / /      #remove 2 fields in attached line
    t               #ommit 1st line
    s/$/1 Marks2/   #arrange header
    ' file.data
```

Other version

```
echo 'Name Marks1 Marks2' ;\
paste -sd' \n' <(tail -n +2 file.data) |
cut -d' ' -f 2,3,6
```

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat crude example:

Here you set the variable `m` to the dates you want to include and their order; as a comma separated string. As per example below that would be:

```
m=2016-10,2016-09
```

Which in turn gives:

```
Name 2016-10 2016-09
```

This require names to be unique and without spaces …

```awk
awk -v m=2016-10,2016-09 '
```

```awk
    NR==1{next}
    {
        # Set array x[name][month]=marks
        x[$2][$1]=$3
    }
    END {
        split(m, k, ",")
        printf "Name"
        for (v in k)
            printf "\t%s", k[v]
        for (e in x) {
            printf "\n%s", e
            for (v in k)
                printf "\t%s", x[e][k[v]]
        }
        print ""
    }
' data
```

Sample output:

```
Name    2016-10 2016-09
Steve   83  39
Mark    71  38
John    64  47
Sam 58  77
```

By `column -t`:

```
Name   2016-10  2016-09
Steve  83       39
Mark   71       38
John   64       47
Sam    58       77
```

---

If  this is a one time thing, and your data is as per example (ordered, only two months etc.) then this could also do:

```
awk 'NR==1{next}NR%2{print $3;next}{printf "%s\t%s\t",$2,$3}' data
```